# 5-6D6 Multinomial Distributions

Tags: probability

So I'm developing a tt-rpg for a project and I wanted to use some non-standard resolution mechanics using 6-sided dice; the normal kind or poker dice depending on how they play out, but I'm having some issues understanding multinomial distributions.

So,

**Method #1** involves rolling anywhere from 1 to 6 D6 and success of a trail is measured in how many times a target number is hit or surpassed usually ≥4, ≥5, or ≥6. (Though the target can be dropped as low as ≥2.) So I need to figure out how likely one is to succeed on a Difficulty 5 check if they roll 6 dice or 4 or 3 or so on and so forth.

**Method #2** is slightly trickier, Using poker dice as a poor-man's stand in for unique non-numerical hieroglyphs the result of a roll is interpreted in terms of X # of successes or failures & Y # of advantages or threats (ala etoe) so if the 6 faces of the dice are re-framed to be interpreted thus:

[+X+Y] [+X] [+Y] [-Y] [-Y] [-X]

if I were to roll 5 of them, what is the likelihood that I get a result of -2X+Y vs a result of 2X-3Y, or a result of 0, etc, etc.

I've tried modeling these formulae in R studio but without any real grasp of statistics I'm a little out of my depth and at the end of my rope.

Thoughts?

Comment: Hi Ed! Could be a little clearer on what you are asking? In your Method #1, does the player decide how many dice to throw? Do they decide what the target number is? What is "a Difficulty 5 check"? I think I can give you a solution, but I want to make sure I understand the problem first.  Can you give an example?  For Method #2, I will write up a solution using generating functions, but please clarify method 1 so I can answer both at the same time.  Cheers!

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, so 1 player decides what the difficulty, or the target number of the check is, saying you need to roll at least 1 of these for the action to be resolved as some kind of success. We actually grade them as Easy (4), Hard (5), and Daunting (6). The number of dice rolled is agreed upon by consensus based on how many relevant abilities a player has. So if I say its a Daunting Check and they only have lets say 3 relevant abilities (3d6) that means they have 3 chances to roll at least one 6.

Comment: ^ the limit of dice that can be rolled at once is 6, and the players have a currency called effort they can spend to drop a target number as low as 2. So the game creates probability questions like 4d6>5 or 6d6>2 etc, etc. Ideally I'd like to put together a table for all the ranges, but 1-6d6 vs an easy, hard or daunting check would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand question 1, you want to find the probability that you will achieve at least one $x$ or greater with $n$ rolls of a $6$-sided die.
This is
$$
1-\left( \frac{x-1}{6} \right)^n.
$$
For example, the probability of getting at least one $5$ or $6$ in $3$ rolls is
$$
1- \left( \frac{5-1}{6} \right)^3 = \frac{19}{27}.
$$

One way to solve question 2 is with a generating function.
Let
$$p = \frac{1}{6}(xy+x+y+2y^{-1}+x^{-1}).$$
Then the coefficient of $x^iy^j$ in $p^m$ is the probability of a result of $i$ $x$'s and $j$ $y$'s in $m$ rolls. The expression $p^5$ is a bit cumbersome, but, reading off coefficients, I find the following probabilities.

With $x$ being the total $X$ and $y$ being the total $Y$, we have:
\begin{array}{ccl}
x & y & \text{prob.} \\
-5& 0& 1/7776\\
-4& -1& 5/3888\\
-4& 1& 5/7776\\
-3& -2& 5/972\\
-3& 0& 5/864\\
-3& 1& 5/7776\\
-3& 2& 5/3888\\
-2& -3& 5/486\\
-2& -1& 5/243\\
-2& 0& 5/972\\
-2& 1& 5/486\\
-2& 2& 5/1944\\
-2& 3& 5/3888\\
-1& -4& 5/486\\
-1& -2& 35/972\\
-1& -1& 5/324\\
-1& 0& 125/3888\\
-1& 1& 35/1944\\
-1& 2& 5/486\\
-1& 3& 5/1296\\
-1& 4& 5/7776\\
0& -5& 1/243\\
0& -3& 5/162\\
0& -2& 5/243\\
0& -1& 95/1944\\
0& 0& 5/108\\
0& 1& 125/3888\\
0& 2& 5/216\\
0& 3& 5/648\\
0& 4& 5/1944\\
0& 5& 1/7776\\
1& -4& 5/486\\
1& -3& 5/486\\
1& -2& 35/972\\
1& -1& 25/486\\
1& 0& 185/3888\\
1& 1& 65/1296\\
1& 2& 55/1944\\
1& 3& 55/3888\\
1& 4& 35/7776\\
1& 5& 5/7776\\
2& -3& 5/486\\
2& -2& 5/243\\
2& -1& 5/162\\
2& 0& 5/108\\
2& 1& 10/243\\
2& 2& 55/1944\\
2& 3& 65/3888\\
2& 4& 5/972\\
2& 5& 5/3888\\
3& -2& 5/972\\
3& -1& 5/324\\
3& 0& 55/2592\\
3& 1& 5/216\\
3& 2& 5/243\\
3& 3& 5/432\\
3& 4& 35/7776\\
3& 5& 5/3888\\
4& -1& 5/3888\\
4& 0& 5/972\\
4& 1& 65/7776\\
4& 2& 5/648\\
4& 3& 5/972\\
4& 4& 5/1944\\
4& 5& 5/7776\\
5& 0& 1/7776\\
5& 1& 5/7776\\
5& 2& 5/3888\\
5& 3& 5/3888\\
5& 4& 5/7776\\
5& 5& 1/7776\\
\end{array}
So, for example,  $-2X+Y$ is attained with probability 
 $\frac{5}{486}$ (from the $x=-2$,$y=1$ row).

Comment: Cheers mate, your a real life saver.

Comment: You're welcome!